# Automatic tab after inputting the text field in java swing?

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

I have tried something but didn't get the result

```
private void txtNameKeyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                   
    String value = txtName.getText();
    digitcheck = value;
    if ((evt.getKeyCode() >= KeyEvent.VK_1 && evt.getKeyCode() <= KeyEvent.VK_2)) 
        {
            txtName.setEditable(true);

            //If the Digit in JTextField exceeds two digits JTextField is deactivated
            if(maxDigit(1))
            {
                try {
                    txtName.setEditable(true);
                    txtAdd.setEnabled(true);
                    Robot robot = new Robot();
                    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
                } catch (AWTException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(Demo.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                txtAdd.setEnabled(false);
            }
        }
        else 
        {
            txtAdd.setEnabled(false);

        }  

}
```

Answer (score 2):

My first through is "why", my second though is "why not use a check box?"

But mine is to do and not question :P

First. I wouldn't use a `KeyListener`.  It's not an appropriate method for filtering text components with, you'd be better using a `DocumentFilter`, this way you can automatically limit the number and type of characters been added to the text field.

Second, I probably wouldn't use `Robot` within this context, but that's just me.

I would probably just use the inbuilt [`transferFocus`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#transferFocus%28%29) method.  It's simpler and takes into account the key transfer API...

```
((AbstractDocument)field1.getDocument()).setDocumentFilter(new DocumentFilter() {

    @Override
    public void insertString(FilterBypass fb, int offset, String string, AttributeSet attr) throws BadLocationException {
        super.insertString(fb, offset, string, attr);
    }

    @Override
    public void remove(FilterBypass fb, int offset, int length) throws BadLocationException {
        super.remove(fb, offset, length);
    }

    @Override
    public void replace(FilterBypass fb, int offset, int length, String text, AttributeSet attrs) throws BadLocationException {
        if (text.startsWith("1") || text.startsWith("2")) {

            field1.transferFocus();

        }
        super.replace(fb, offset, length, text, attrs);
    }

});
```

Have a look at [here](http://www.jroller.com/dpmihai/entry/documentfilter) for a number of excellent examples of the `DocumentFilter`